# Adding dynamically third party javascript widgets to the web app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a React js project where I should dynamically add third party scripts (widgets) to the web app.

Widgets include any kind of third party platforms: Twitter, Instagram, Youplay, Youtube etc.

The current code that I have looks like this:

```
    appendThirdPartyScript(externalScript) {
    // Create an element outside the document to parse the string with
    const head = document.createElement("head");

    // Parse the string
    head.innerHTML = externalScript;

    // Copy those nodes to the real `head`, duplicating script elements so
    // they get processed
    let node = head.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        const next = node.nextSibling;
        if (node.tagName === "SCRIPT") {
            // Just appending this element wouldn't run it, we have to make a fresh copy
            const newNode = document.createElement("script");
            if (node.src) {
                newNode.src = node.src;
            }
            while (node.firstChild) {
                // Note we have to clone these nodes
                newNode.appendChild(node.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
                node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
            }
            node = newNode;
        }
        document.head.appendChild(node);
        node = next;
    }
}
```

So basically the scripts urls comes from the backend/api and that is a list of scripts smth like `['http://twitter-widget.js', 'http://instagram-widget.js']`

So since I have an array of scripts as string I use a for loop to go thru each of element and call **appendThirdPartyScript('somescript')**

```
data.externalScripts.map(script => {
      this.appendThirdPartyScript("" + script);
});
```

This solution worked for almost all cases until I came to this case:
['http://embed.tt.se/v10/tt-widget.js', 'new tt.TTWidget({WhereToAddWidget: 'tt-quiz-XMuxmuWHc',type: 'quiz',ID: 'xxx',clientID: 'xxx',});']

So basically the error I get is:

> tt is not a function

I am assuming that the first script hasn't completed loading (in this case **http://embed.tt.se/v10/tt-widget.js**) and the next one is trying to call something that does not exists.

When I try to hard code http://embed.tt.se/v10/tt-widget.js within head tag in index.html directly than it works!

So this approach of dynamically adding third party widgets is not reliable. Anyone can let me know if my current code needs to be changed or any suggestion would be pretty much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but probably not best solution:

```
 const delayTime = 500; 
    externalScriptArray.forEach((script, index) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.appendNewTagElementToDom(script);
        }, delayTime*index);
    });
```